# Select data from other table during insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am inserting data into a database that looks like this:
`(1, 'blue'), (2,'large'), (3, 'round')`

The numbers there correspond to ID's from another table. that looks like: `id | value`

When inserting this data I want to insert the actual value that the number corresponds to, not the id.

Is there any query to do this? or do I need match the values before sending it to the database?

While I know it won't work, I am hoping there is something like:
`insert into table2 (table1.value[id=1], 'blue'), (table1.value[id=2],'large'), (table1.value[id=3], 'round') join table1`

I imagine I could use:

```
insert into table2 
    ((select value from table1 where id=1), 'blue'), 
    ((select value from table1 where id=2),'large'), 
    ((select value from table1 where id=3), 'round')
```

But with say, 40 different attributes that would make 41 queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First virtually make up a table with the values you want to insert (id,value), then join the derived table to table1 and INSERT the result into table2.

```
insert into table2
     select t.value, madeup.other
       from (select 1 id, 'blue' other union all
             select 2, 'large' union all
             select 3, 'round') madeup
       join table1 t on t.id = madeup.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary table to map id to value. I don't really speak MySQL, but something like this:

```
create table #mapping (id int, description varchar)
insert into #mapping values (1, 'blue')
insert into #mapping values (2, 'large')
insert into #mapping values (3, 'round')

insert into table2 
select table1.value, #mapping.description
from #mapping
join table1 on table1.id = #mapping.id

drop table #mapping
```